# The time evolution in Dirac delta potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

We know that the dirac delta potential has exactly one bound state. If the potential strength suddenly changes a value, the bound state should evolve to the new bound state, how to describe the time evolution for this system? How to decompose the initial bound state to eigenstates in the new potential?

Comment: This sounds like a problem that could be solved nicely with time-dependent perturbation theory. You need to be more specific though in how your potential changes - are you changing the "height" of the delta function (i.e. $\delta (x_0) \rightarrow (1-\epsilon) \delta (x_0)$, or are you adding a second potential at a different $x$, or possibly something else?

You may have a bit of problem using perturbation theory on this potential though (depending on the type of change you are thinking of) because it doesn't have a nice set of eigenstates.

Comment: I'd recommend the "sudden approximation". You assume that the time scale on which the potential changes is small compared to the time scale on which your bound state evolves, then you can calculate the amplitude that the system remains in the bound state simply by calculating the inner product of the old and new bound states. (Getting the probability of the bound state being broken works analogously).